# XFBML Like Buttons not Loading while dynamically generating multiple posts on a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, facebook, xfbml

I have a page with multiple posts. And I am trying to add a `Facebook LIKE` button for every post on this page. I am using `XFBML` code for populating like buttons under each post with a different URL i.e. Post URL.

[image]

The Code Goes Here :

First of all I have included:

in Head

```
<meta property="og:title" content="TITLE" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://MY_URL" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="TEST" />
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="TEST" />
    <meta property="fb:app_id" content="MY_App_ID" />
```

in HTML tag:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#" >
```

And in Body, I am generating the each post in a loop using javascript this way

```
strHTML += '<span>Hello This is a Post Start</span>';
// generating a variable url for each post using my Object List
varUrlTemp = 'https://17path.wordpress.com/?date=' + objListing.ListingId ;
    strHTML += '<fb:like href="' + varUrlTemp + '" layout="button_count" action="like" show_faces="false" share="false"></fb:like>';
    strHTML += '<script>(function (d, s, id) {';
    strHTML += 'var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];';
    strHTML += 'if (d.getElementById(id)) return;';
    strHTML += 'js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;';
    strHTML += 'js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=MY_APP_ID_Here";';
    strHTML += 'fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);';
strHTML += '<span>Hello This is a Post End</span>';
    strHTML += '} (document, "script", "facebook-jssdk"));</script>';
```

The Code is working fine whenever the page loads. All the like buttons for intial posts loaded correctly But When I click on "Load More" Button in the End, its not loading "Like Buttons" for newer posts on the page.

Comment: For the time i have solved the situation using iFrame code for generating LIKE buttons. But I really looking why is it not working with XFBML code for Facebook Like.

Answer (score 0):

After appending buttons with iframe parse the Dom again with

```
FB.XFBML.parse(document.getElementById("containerid"));
```

make sure that every button has parent with different ids.

and try with `FB.XFBML.parse();` I hope it works :)

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But I have delievered it with iFrame version :)